# ExtJS Duplicate Column Headers Conflict in Grid

Tags: extjs, grid, duplicates, extjs4

I want to have a grid that allows duplicate column names, but to contain different data. Apparently this causes a conflict and the column with duplicate name just copy the data from the first column and moves the other data.

Here is what i mean. I have a column "FirstName" that i want to rename to "Login":
[image]

I rename it, but "Login" already exists and this happens:

[image]

My store is added dynamically to the grid like this:

```
var columnNames = ["RecordID", "RowDateModified", "Login", "ActionType", "DateModified", "RawDataSetSyncDiscardedType", "ID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Email", "Gender"]
var myData = [["3000010032", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.2600000", "Administrator", "I", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.3570000", "COMMITTED", "3", "Lawrence", "Stone", "lstone2@toplist.cz", "Male"],["3000010033", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.2600000", "Administrator", "I", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.3570000", "COMMITTED", "2", "Karen", "Dean", "kdean1@ovh.net", "Female"],["3000010034", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.2600000", "Administrator", "I", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.3570000", "COMMITTED", "4", "Marie", "Carter", "mcarter3@jiathis.com", "Female"],["3000010035", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.2600000", "Administrator", "I", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.3570000", "COMMITTED", "6", "Lawrence", "Richardson", "lrichardson5@ovh.net", "Male"]]

dataStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
fields: columnNames,
data: myData
});

for (var i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
columnsArr.push({
    text: columnNames[i],
    sortable: true,
    forceFit: true,
    minWidth: 150,
    dataIndex: columnNames[i]
});
}

grid.reconfigure(dataStore, columnsArr);
```

EDIT: `columnNames` and `myData` are dynamically generated. When I rename a column, the renaming function returns different `columnNames` array.

I'm doubting that this is ExtJS problem, but it doesn't make sense to not be able to use duplicate names in a table.

My question is Am I doing something wrong (like missing a property) or I should go with some workaround to solve this?

I'm using ExtJS 4.0.7

Comment: But you have not shown the code how you are renaming the column name?

Comment: @ankitchaudhary Actually `columnNames` is dynamically populated and when I rename something it just return different array. I think the renaming function is not related, that's why i didn't post it. Though, I will clarify in my question that `columnNames` is dynamically generated data.

Comment: Oh..then you cannot use same array to map text and dataindex. As text means what is column name and dataIndex means which field value should be shown. So its not a ExtJs problem. Do you always have to rename FirstName to login?

Comment: Well yeah, but not necessarily - It might be any other column. The user is not prevented in renaming the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtJS bind your data to your column with the `dataIndex` field. But you setted the same `dataIndex` to your two columns. Thats is why you have the same data in your two columns.

Just use one *array* to set the `text` of your column and another one to set the `dataIndex`

```
var columnNames = ["RecordID", "RowDateModified", "Login", "ActionType", "DateModified", "RawDataSetSyncDiscardedType", "ID", "Login", "LastName", "Email", "Gender"];
var columnDataIndexes = ["RecordID", "RowDateModified", "Login", "ActionType", "DateModified", "RawDataSetSyncDiscardedType", "ID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Email", "Gender"]
var myData = [["3000010032", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.2600000", "Administrator", "I", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.3570000", "COMMITTED", "3", "Lawrence", "Stone", "lstone2@toplist.cz", "Male"],["3000010033", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.2600000", "Administrator", "I", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.3570000", "COMMITTED", "2", "Karen", "Dean", "kdean1@ovh.net", "Female"],["3000010034", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.2600000", "Administrator", "I", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.3570000", "COMMITTED", "4", "Marie", "Carter", "mcarter3@jiathis.com", "Female"],["3000010035", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.2600000", "Administrator", "I", "2017-04-25 09:11:47.3570000", "COMMITTED", "6", "Lawrence", "Richardson", "lrichardson5@ovh.net", "Male"]]

dataStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
fields: columnDataIndexes,
data: myData
});

for (var i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
columnsArr.push({
    text: columnNames[i], // <<== Column names array
    sortable: true,
    forceFit: true,
    minWidth: 150,
    dataIndex: columnDataIndexes[i] // <<== Different array here (dataIndexes)
});
}

grid.reconfigure(dataStore, columnsArr);
```

Comment: @Nyagolova Did you try with the two arrays? I think you really should have two array, one for your `dataIndex` and the other one for the `columnsNames`

Comment: Yeah, but i used the second array only in columnsArr, when i should've change it in the dataStore too. When I did that it worked :) Thanks for the help